# Showing killing form is Ad-invariant

Tags: lie-algebras

Let $G$ be a matrix Lie group. Its Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ comes equipped with a symmetric (2,0) tensor known as its Killing from, denoted $K$ and defined by 
$$
K(X,Y) = -\text{Tr}(\text{ad}_X \circ \text{ad}_Y)$$

where $\text{ad}_X \in \text{GL}(\mathfrak{g})$ defined by $\text{ad}_X(Y)= [X,Y]$. Show that $K$ is Ad-invariant, in the sense that 
$$ 
K(\text{Ad}_A(X), \text{Ad}_A(Y)) = K(X,Y) \quad \forall X,Y \in \mathfrak{g}, A \in G $$.

Here $\text{Ad}_A(X) = AXA^{-1} \in \mathfrak{g}$.

I suppose that it suffices to prove it on a basis, but it isn't a big deal to let $X$ and $Y$ be arbitrary. Choosing a basis $E_j$ for $\mathfrak{g}$, I write
$$
[E_j,E_k] = {c_{jk}}^l E_l
$$
$$
X = a^kE_k, Y = b^kE_k
$$
and 
$$
AE_kA^{-1} = {d_k}^lE_l.
$$
Then
$$ [X,[Y,E_m]] = [a^kE_k,[b^lE_l,E_m]] = a^kb^l {c_{kn}}^j {c_{lm}}^n E_j$$
and so the trace of this operator is $a^kb^l{c_{kn}}^j{c_{lj}}^n$. The left hand side is
$$ 
[AXA^{-1},[AYA^{-1},E_m]] = [a^k{d_k}^lE_l,[b^n {d_n}^j E_j,E_m]]= a^kb^n{d_k}^l{d_n}^j {c_{jm}}^r {c_{lr}}^k E_k$$ so the trace of this operator is
$$
a^kb^n{d_n}^j{d_k}^l{c_{jk}}^r{c_{lr}}^k
$$ 
assuming the indices are correct. Now these two have to be the same somehow. Using that $\text{Ad}_A{[X,Y]}=[\text{Ad}_A{X}, \text{Ad}_A{Y}]$ may be promising, but I haven't found anything useful with it. A hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: Start by verifying (best without expanding in terms of a basis) that $ad_{Ad_A(X)}=Ad_A\circ ad_X\circ Ad_{A^{-1}}$, then use what you know about compatibility of the trace with similarity of linear maps.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to show this, and therefore that $ad_{Ad_A(X)} \circ ad_{Ad_A(Y)} = Ad_A \circ ad_X \circ ad_Y \circ Ad_{A^{-1}}$. The problem is I don't view $X \to AXA^{-1}$ as a similarity transform but as a linear transformation on $\mathfrak{g}$, if that is what you mean. I'm not sure what else I can glean from it.

Comment: The similarity argument is not applied to the linear maps $X$ and $AXA^{-1}$ but to linear maps $\mathfrak g\to\mathfrak g$. Just take into account that $Ad_{A^{-1}}=(Ad_A)^{-1}$.